# Finding the missing element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

An Array A contains n-1 unique integers in the range [0,n-1], that is , there is one number from this range that is not in A. Design an O(n)- time algorithm for finding that number. You are allowed to use only O(logn) additional space besides the array A itself.

Anyone can help?

Comment: sum the elements of the range and the array and calculate the difference

Comment: This is a duplicate, surely? A search for "array missing element" returns 2662 results.

Answer (score 3):

sum of consecutive integers from 0 to n-1 , S = n*(n-1)/2;
sum of array , s=calcSum(array)           // O(n) complexity, one loop required

missing number = S-s;

Complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(1)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using summation formula, it is better to use XOR operator to find the missing element in an array. Because summation can overflow for a very big integer. On the other end, XOR operator will not cause such problem.

```
// C# program to find missing Number
// using xor

using System;

class Program
{
    // Function to find missing number
    static int getMissingElement (int []a, int n)
    {
        int x1 = a[0]; 
        int x2 = 1; 

        /* For xor of all the elements 
        in array */
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            x1 = x1 ^ a[i];

        /* For xor of all the elements 
        from 1 to n+1 */   
        for (int i = 2; i <= n + 1; i++) // loop to n+1 because including the missing 
 //number the size of the array will increase by 1
            x2 = x2 ^ i;         

        return (x1 ^ x2); // return final xor result
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int []a = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};
        int miss = getMissingElement(a, 5); // size of array is 5
        Console.Write(miss);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, You could perhaps get away with a single loop by initializing `x2` to `n` and moving `x2 ^= i` into the first for() loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def finder(arr1,arr2):
    d={}
    for i in arr1:
        if i in d: 
            d[i]+=1 # if the number is repeated, the value is incremented with 1
        else:
            d[i]=1 # adds all the numbers which are not present in the dictionary
    #print(d)
    for i in arr2:
        if i in d:
            d[i]-=1 # if the number is repeated, the value is decremented with 1
        else:
            d[i]=1 # adds all the numbers which are not present in the dictionary
    #print(d)
    for i in d:
        if d[i]!=0: # The value must not be zero if any number is missing from any of the two arrays, so it will print the missing number(s)
            print(i)
        else:
            return 'No Missing element'



finder(x,y)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
     * Time Complexity will be 
     * Arrays.sort(A)  = O (n log n)
     * Binary Search O (log n)
     * 
     * Total Time Complexity = O (n log n) + O (log n)
     * 
     * @param A
     * @return
     */
    private static int getMissingElement(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);

        int low = 0;
        int high = A.length-1;
        int missingElement = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (A[mid] != mid+1) {
                high = mid - 1;
                missingElement = mid +1;
            }
            else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        if(missingElement == 0){
            return A.length+1;
        }
        return missingElement;
    }
```

Comment: using binary search, we can achieve this solution. Assume the array is sorted, If it is not then use Arrays.sort(A).

Comment: You should put your comment in your actual answer (there is an edit button). In reply to it though you can't assume it is sorted and if you need to call sort can you do that in O(n) time?

Comment: @Chris hope you understood the explanation provided.

Comment: While you are being much clearer you haven't addressed the fact that the OP required an "O(n)- time algorithm" whereas yours is O (n log n) - it doesn't seem to actual fit the requirements of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Procedure to approach this question would be:

1. Sort the elements in the array using any sorting algorithm of
   choice depending on the complexity you want
2. Loop through the sorted Array
3. Check to see if the arr[index + 1] - arr[index] != 1, then
   It indicates, a number is missing
   Get the **difference**  between these **indexes**
4. Create a temporary list to store missing numbers
5. Using a **for-loop**, from 1 up to the **difference range**, add
   1 to the **arr[index]**  and store in **missingNumbers** list
6. Now loop through **missingNumbers list**, to get all your missing  numbers

An implementation using Java which caters for both **(negative and positive)** numbers

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class missingElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int values[] =  {17, 1, -4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10 ,15,23};
    
    int[] arrSorted = sortValues(values);

    //pass sorted Array to get Missing Numbers
    List<Integer> results = getMissingNumbers(arrSorted);
    for (int value : results) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

public static int[] sortValues(int[] arr) {
    // sort in asc first (any sort algo will do depending on the complexity you want
    // going with bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                int temp = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static List<Integer> getMissingNumbers(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> missingNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
            if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] != 1) {
                int rangeLeft = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
                for(int k=1; k < rangeLeft; k++) {
                    missingNumbers.add(arr[i] + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return missingNumbers;
  }
 }
```

[image: Program Run on console sample output]

Comment: This is not an O(n) solution

Comment: Sorry, didn't check for the complexity on the question, as two nested for loops produce 0(n**2). Good for the feedback though